# How to map a nullable enum to string in Mongo C# client

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've a document with a nullable enum like this:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}

public class Person {
    public Gender? Gender { get; set;}
}
```

I'm using `MongoDB C# Driver` and has mapped the enum to be serialize as a string:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(map =>
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    map.MapMember(x => x.Gender).SetSerializer(new EnumSerializer<Gender>(BsonType.String);
});
```

This works fine for non-nullable types, but failed for this nullable enum:

> Value type of serializer is Gender and does not match member type
> System.Nullable`1[[Gender]]. (Parameter 'serializer')

How can I map a nullable enum to a string ?

Comment: check this [solution](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2530) from MongoDB driver

Comment: Or this would help : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Conventions/EnumRepresentationConvention.cs

Comment: You can fix that by setting a DefaultValue attribute on the property, e.g. `[DefaultValue(MyEnumType.Default)]`

Answer (score 2):

There is a special wrapper just for your case - `NullableSerializer<T>`. Use it like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(map =>
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    map.MapMember(x => x.Gender).SetSerializer(new NullableSerializer<Gender>(new EnumSerializer<Gender>(BsonType.String)));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What are the pros and cons using this `SetSerializer` method vs. using `ConventionRegistry` and the `EnumRepresentationConvention` posted above?  Except that the first is for each map member whereas the other is on a global level.